# Insert statement returning 'object has no attribute 'uuid'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aws-lambda

I'm working to insert some code into sql server and I keep running into the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": 'str' object has no attribute 'uuid'"
  "errorType": AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
   File \"/var/task/data_insert/clean_sweep.py\", line 17 , row.uuid\n"
  ]
}
```

My code looks like:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
my_bucket = 'data-staging'
data_filename = 'data_pull.csv'
insert_csv = client.get_object(Bucket = my_bucket, Key = data_filename)
data_body = insert_csv["body"]
csv_string = data_body.read().decode('utf-8')
data_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string))

conn = pymssql.connect(server = 'rds_sqlserver.com', user='etl_xu',password = 'XU2014basketball', database = 'Xacation')
cursor = conn.cursor()
for row in data_df.itterrows():
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO xac.staging(uuid, last_name, xac_account)
                        VALUES(?,?,?)
                        '''
                        , row.uuid
                        , row.last_name
                        , row.xac_account
                        )
```

I thought skipping over the first row due to it being headers would fix it but it's really not the case. Help please!

Comment: Where are you skipping the headers?  And if you are skipping the headers, how is pandas supposed to know you have a column called `uuid`?  Have you printed `data_df` to see what you're actually getting?

Comment: Building off Tim's comment, sometimes with CSVs there's extra whitespace in the column names. Check that you don't have `"uuid "` for example.

Comment: yep, so I did update my code to the following `for row in data_df[1:]` to make sure I got the next row and it still gave me the same error just with `"errorMessage": 'str' object has no attribute 'uuid'"` 

When printing data_df I got `hq948h4q4`,`Vasquez`, 0777848502

Comment: @26Cocktails: that wouldn't make any difference because each row has the attributes or doesn't.

Comment: @26Cocktails: `print(data_df.columns)` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is the source of your problem:

```
csv_string = data_body.read().decode('utf-8')
data_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string))
```

S3 objects Bodies are returned as a stream. You are reading the stream into an object and then attempting to re stream it with the StringIO -

I stream in XML files from s3 into `xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring()` all the time which expects some sort byte stream or string - and simply use:

```
xml_s3_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key)['Body'].read()
tree = ET.fromstring(xml_s3_object)
```

So because you are decoding it and then restreaming it with StringIO you are likely causing some encoding/decoding errors that are causing issues in your rows.

Comment: so you're saying remove the stingIO?

Comment: When I print my df out after `csv_string = data_body.read().decode('utf-8')
data_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string)) ` it prints everything just fine.

Comment: print() will read it according to the UTF-8 you decoded it as, so it will 'look' fine but there may be something in their that print doesn't show. 

But ... i could also be wrong in this.